# parsing large xml file with Python - etree.parse error

Tags: python, xml, lxml

Trying to parse the following Python file using the lxml.etree.iterparse function.

"sampleoutput.xml"

```
<item>
  <title>Item 1</title>
  <desc>Description 1</desc>
</item>
<item>
  <title>Item 2</title>
  <desc>Description 2</desc>
</item>
```

I tried the code from [Parsing Large XML file with Python lxml and Iterparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182234/parsing-large-xml-file-with-python-lxml-and-iterparse)

before the etree.iterparse(MYFILE) call I did MYFILE = open("/Users/eric/Desktop/wikipedia_map/sampleoutput.xml","r")

But it turns up the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/eric/Documents/Programming/Eclipse_Workspace/wikipedia_mapper/testscraper.py", line 6, in <module>
    for event, elem in context :
  File "iterparse.pxi", line 491, in lxml.etree.iterparse.__next__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:98565)
  File "iterparse.pxi", line 543, in lxml.etree.iterparse._read_more_events (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:99086)
  File "parser.pxi", line 590, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:74712)
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Extra content at the end of the document, line 5, column 1
```

any ideas? thank you!

Comment: Could it be that your XML file is malformed? It contains no `<?xml` tag or a root element.

Comment: I don't know lxml, but your example isn't valid XML.  An XML document has to have a single root element.  Yours doesn't.

Comment: you need a root element, not only child nodes.

Comment: Is there a way to ignore not having a root element?

Comment: Yes, I edited the accepted answer with some solutions. There are two: 1. pretend it's html (using the html flag in the parser), 2. wrap the file object with something that adds root elements.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that XML isn't well-formed if it doesn't have exactly one top-level tag. You can fix your sample by wrapping the entire document in `<items></items>` tags. You also need the `<desc/>` tags to match the query that you're using (`description`).

The following document produces correct results with your existing code:

```
<items>
  <item>
    <title>Item 1</title>
    <description>Description 1</description>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>Item 2</title>
    <description>Description 2</description>
  </item>
</items>
```

Comment: what if the file is so large and i don't want to load it in memory so i am parsing it using iterparse ?

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, xml.etree.ElementTree usually expects the XML file to contain one "root" element, i.e. one XML tag that encloses the complete document structure. From the error message you posted I would assume that this is the problem here as well:

´Line 5´ refers to the second `<item>` tag, so I guess Python complains that there is more data following after the assumed root element (i.e. the first `<item>` tag) was closed.