# Parsing a partial XML with python lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I'm trying to parse a large XML file which is being received from the network in Python.

In order to do that, I get the data and pass it to `lxml.etree.iterparse`

However, if the XML has yet to fully be sent, like so:

```
<MyXML>
    <MyNode foo="bar">
    <MyNode foo="ba
```

If I run `etree.iterparse(f, tag='MyNode').next()` I get an `XMLSyntaxError` at whereever it was cut off.

Is there any way I can make it so I can receive the first tag (i.e. the first MyNode) and only get an exception when I reach that part of the document? (To make lxml really 'stream' the contents and not read the whole thing in the beginning).

Answer (score 2):

[XMLPullParser](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.XMLPullParser-class.html) and [HTMLPullParser](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.XMLPullParser-class.html) may better suite your needs. They get their data by repeated calls to `parser.feed(data)`. You still have to wait until all of the data comes in before the tree is usable.

Comment: That's problematic though, as the data I'm receiving "may" never be fully received.

Comment: That is a problem. As of python 3.4, lxml has [Incremental event parsing](http://lxml.de/parsing.html#incremental-event-parsing). Maybe you could keep track of the element stack and feed closing elements to the parser when your data stream dies. It wouldn't work if you were mid-element though (`<alert warning="help I'm being attacked by a...`).

Comment: I need to support python 2.7, and I do need to support being mid-element, too.

Answer (score -1):

Try to learn from the answers of two related questions to your problem. Find more wisdom in more related answers. Your problem is very common, may be you need to tweak it a bit to fit into a proven solution. Prefer that way to create a stable solution.

- [using lxml and iterparse() to parse a big (+- 1Gb) XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856163/using-lxml-and-iterparse-to-parse-a-big-1gb-xml-file)
- [Parsing Large XML file with Python lxml and Iterparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182234/parsing-large-xml-file-with-python-lxml-and-iterparse)

Comment: None of those have anything about parsing a partial XML, though.