# python elemnttree throw me "kill"

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm trying to parse xml file using elemnttree.
The size of the xml is 1.5GB.
I run the code from th terminal and after these lines:

```
def parse_xml(file_path):
     ett = ET.ElementTree(file=file_path)
```

I'm getting in the console the print "Killed" without any further message.
Can anyone know the reason?

Thank you

Comment: size `1.5` of what ? KB, MB, GB? Did you run script directly in console/terminal/cmd.exe? Did you check if this file has really xml data?

Comment: It's 1.5GB. (i edited the post). I run it from the terminal and yes, if I open the file with "less" command i can see it's xml file.

Comment: maybe you should use other xml module to read it partially.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid that

Comment: [Parsing a partial XML with python lxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27571623/parsing-a-partial-xml-with-python-lxml)